# How do I count the number of commits made in to all repos hosted by gitosis on my server

Tags: git, gitosis

I am trying to found out the total number of commits made across all repositories hosted on a gitosis install I have. Anyone have any ideas to how I may do this?

Comment: First, why? Second, have you tried anything?

Comment: I want to get the total number of commits to display on a web page. I have tried the one solution listed below, however, the git user doesn't actually have ssh access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ls /path/to/repos/ | xargs -I % git --git-dir=/path/to/repos/%/.git rev-list --all 2>/dev/null | wc -l
```

That works fairly well for me. You can `grep -v zip` or use a more specific `find` query to just find specific directories, too.

*Update*: use `rev-list --all` instead of `log --pretty=oneline`.

Comment: As @manojlds points out, `rev-list --all` will actually be better.

Answer (score 2):

There are certain ways to count the number of commits like:

```
git rev-list --all | wc -l
```

or for a branch

```
git log branch --pretty=oneline | wc -l
```

Can you use that on each repo or write a script that goes to each of the repo, runs any of the above and get the count?

Answer (score 1):

For newer versions of git (tested on 2.14.1), the command `git rev-list --count HEAD` will work, and give the same result as `git rev-list --all | wc -l`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a feature in gitosis that do it, but since gitosis saves all the repositories in one directory it is quite simple.

For instance, the default gitosis installation (well, or at least mine :)) stores the repositories in ~git/repositories.

Go to that directory and execute something similar to this:

```
for rep in `find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -print`; do 
    echo $rep; 
    (cd $rep && git log -pretty=oneline | wc -l); 
done
```

Can probably do it neater, but it shows the repository followed by the commit count.

Comment: Don't do grep on commit. Many commit messages have `commit` in them. There can be git notes displayed as well.

Comment: `git log` takes params like `--pretty=oneline` to help with things like this.

Comment: Good thinking. Didn't know about that ´--pretty=oneline´. I knew there was something like that, but couldn't find it. Thanks, have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

On my gitosis server i use this command

```
cd /path/to/repos/
ls | xargs -I % git --git-dir=% rev-list --all 2>/dev/null | wc -l
```

And in gitorious server i use

```
array=($(ls /path/to/repos/))
for i in ${array[@]}; do cd /path/to/repos/$i; ls | xargs -I % git --git-dir=% rev-list --all 2>/dev/null | wc -l; done
```

This will show the commits for all projects, you should add on your own

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend making an "inspection repository". I use gitolite but the process would be the same:

First create a repo that gathers commits from all the repositories:

```
git init --bare all && cd all
ssh gitolite@gitserver | grep @W | xargs -i{} git remote add {} gitolite@gitserver:{}.git
git fetch --all
```

Now you should be able to get a count by doing a line count:

```
git log --all --format=%h | wc -l
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think he's looking for total number of commits, across all repos, not number of repos.